# Laravel 5.4 - get entrys where column contains specific string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-pagination

I'm geting the following error if I try to get database entrys where the name contains a passed string.

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

.

```
$search = $request['search'];
$key_search = explode(' ', $search);
$usergroups = Usergroups::whereIn('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')->paginate(3);
```

$key_search looks something like this: `[0 => "Test", 1 => "Unicorn"];`

Now I want to get every entry where the name column has data that contains the passed strings and get the query results with `paginate();`

I've also tried something like a foreach loop that pushes the entrys into another array but this haven't worked for me as well cause the entrys are Objects and not arrays. Thats why array_push coulnd't handle this.

Does someone know what I can do to get the entrys?

Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad english!

---

Based on answer:

Problem is that I get every entry in my database. At first the entrys that matches with the search keys and the last entrys doesn't match with the search keys at all.

example:

I'm passing "test" and "unicorn"

And I have 10 entrys in my database. For example:

1. test dkkawdmawkdkaw
2. mdkawdawtestdmwakdaw // test
3. apples
4. oranges
5. anything
6. Unicorn  /// Unicorn - U is uppercase
7. more unicornsdawdawd //unicorn
8. pizza
9. testing
10. i'm not creative

So I only want: 1,2,6,7 and 9. But I'm getting all of them sorted from high matches to doesn't match at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`whereIn()` can not be used for like query.

```
$usergroups = Usergroups::query();

foreach($key_search as $search) {
  $usergroups = $usergroups->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
}

$usergroups = $usergroups->paginate(3);

// Results in
// select * from `usergroups` where `name` like ? or where `name` like ?;
```

You can also try this.

```
$usergroups = Usergroups::where(function ($query) use ($key_search) {
                            foreach($key_search as $search) {
                              $query->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
                            }
                          })->paginate(3);

// Results in
// select * from `usergroups` where (`name` like ? or `name` like ?;
```

[image: Test DB]
[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks, thats working perfect! I've tried a similar way but whey to complicated :D Thanks !

Comment: I've realized that this code gives me every entry back. In $key_search is test and paginate as a search string. Now I have 3 entrys with test in the name column and 3 with paginate. But I also get entrys where the name is doesn't contain the strings. Have I did something wrong with the '%' . $search . '%' ?

Comment: @dwdawdawdaw Are you looking for a where() query? Try using only `where()` instead of `orWhere()`? Also are you sure you are looking for a **like** query? Or you need exact matches?

Comment: Please have a look at my question. I've updated it to explain my problem better

Comment: @dwdawdawdaw Both the queries I have given should work fine. Just tested out on a sample table.

Comment: hmm if I search for Test ( uppercase ) I don't find entrys where test is written in lowercase.But anyway, how can I only take for example only 5 items? like:

Comment: $usergroups = Usergroups::where(function ($query) use ($key_search) {
            foreach($key_search as $search) {
                $query->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
            }
        })->take(5);
        $usergroups = $usergroups->paginate(2);

Comment: well, thats interesting o.o

Comment: Like queries work for **upper** and **lower** both. Also to paginate, u need to first do `take(5)` and then pass this collection into the `LengthAwarePaginator` - Read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `whereIn()` like this. Use multiple `orWhere()` instead, for example:

```
$searchArray = explode(' ', $request->search);
$userGroups = Usergroups::query();
foreach ($searchArray as $searchValue) {
    $userGroups = $userGroups->orWhere('name', 'like', '%'.$searchValue.'%');
}
$userGroups = $userGroups->paginate(3);
```

Comment: thanks! your and prateekkathals answer are the same, I've voted for your answers :) thanks alot!

Comment: I've also wrote this comment to prateekkathal :
 I've realized that this code gives me every entry back. In $key_search is test and paginate as a search string. Now I have 3 entrys with test in the name column and 3 with paginate. But I also get entrys where the name is doesn't contain the strings. Have I did something wrong with the '%' . $search . '%' ?